# Insert Image into a Google Sheet with Apps Script using base64 encoded data

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, base64

Given some base64 encoded data for a png file, as in the example below from the image tag.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAAAAAMAAwAAAMlWLPcGjDKFYi9lxKBOaGcF35DhWHamZUW0K4mAbiwWtuf0uxFAgA7">
```

I need to create an image blob from the base64 encoded data for the `insertImage()` method.

```
sheetClass.insertImage(imageBlob, column, row)
```

Documentation:
[Sheets Class - insertImage method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#insertImage(BlobSource,Integer,Integer))

I've tried using the code below, but it throws the error:

> Execution failed: Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL

The documentation states that the method needs a blob, not a URL, but it seems like it's expecting a link to an image file.

```
function insertImageFromBase64Src() {
  var data = 'R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAAAAAMAAwAAAMlWLPcGjDKFYi9lxKBOaGcF35DhWHamZUW0K4mAbiwWtuf0uxFAgA7';

  var imageBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), 'image/png').getBytes();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//This code is bound to a Sheet

  var po = {
    shName:'Update File',
    column:1,
    row:37
  }

  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(po.shName);

  var image = sh.insertImage(imageBlob, po.column, po.row);//Insert an image and return the image
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `insertImage` can use the blob and URL which is the direct link of the image file.

  - In your script, `imageBlob` is an byte array which is "number[]". By this, I think that an error occurs.
- Please add the name to the blob.

  - When the name is not given, an error occurs.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function insertImageFromBase64Src2() {
  var data = 'R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAAAAAMAAwAAAMlWLPcGjDKFYi9lxKBOaGcF35DhWHamZUW0K4mAbiwWtuf0uxFAgA7';

  var imageBlob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), 'image/png', 'sample');  // Modified

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //This code is bound to a Sheet

  var po = {
    shName:'Update File',
    column:1,
    row:37
  }

  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(po.shName);

  var image = sh.insertImage(imageBlob, po.column, po.row);//Insert an image and return the image
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `data` can be correctly decoded.

#### References:

- [insertImage(blobSource, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row)
- [insertImage(url, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageurl,-column,-row)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you.  It works.  Interestingly, if the blob name `sample` is removed, it gives an error.  So, for some reason the `insertImage` method seems to be expecting that the blob has a name.

Comment: @Alan Wells Thank you for replying. Yes. Also, I thought that if the image on Spreadsheet could be retrieved by the file name of image, it might help to manage the images on Spreadsheet.

Comment: Good point.  If there were multiple images in the Sheet, then having a name for each one would help identify them.  I also found another interesting solution.  I can use the data url:`var data = 'base64Encoded data here';var url = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;sh = ss.getSheetByName(po.shName);var image = sh.insertImage(url, column, row);`  But that solution doesn't give the image a name.

Comment: @Alan Wells Thank you for replying and adding the information. I think that it is a good approach. I had thought that the URL can use only the direct link of the image file. But from your additional information, it was found that the url of data image can be also used. In this case, the base64 data is encoded at the internal server. So I thought that the cost might be lower than that of the process for encoding on the client side.

Comment: What I'm doing is hard coding the base64 data image data in order to avoid an external request to an image url or reading Google Drive to get an image file.  I'm trying to create an add-on with as few permissions needed as possible.  What would be really great is if there were a way to get the base64 data from html.  `var html = "<button>Submit</button>";` Obviously the html for the button is a lot less hard coded data than the base64 data.