# Google Apps Script Utilities.base64Decode Exception: Could not decode string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have base64 encoded a png image which is placed in Google Sheet cell. Need to decode this in Google App Script to image and using following code.

**CODE**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var strBase64Image = ss.getRange('F1').getValue()
ss.getRange('F2').setValue(strBase64Image); // test fn is working
var decodedBytes = Utilities.base64Decode(strBase64Image); // decode to byte array
var blobImg = Utilities.newBlob(decodedBytes, MimeType.PNG); // create blog from byte array
ss.insertImage(blobImg, 6, 3); // write image to F3 cell
```

**ERROR**

> Exception: Could not decode string.

This base64 encoded png image string is getting decoded to image when tested in https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. The 2nd argument of `Utilities.base64Decode()` is `charset`. But in your script, `MineType.PNG` is used. And, in this case, an error occurs at `MineType.PNG`, because `MineType` is not defined. How about this? 2. How about using the name of blob at `Utilities.newBlob(decodedBytes, MimeType.PNG)`? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60496722/7108653) 3. Does your base64 data have the header? If the header is added, please remove it and test it again.

Comment: var decodedBytes = Utilities.base64Decode(strBase64Image, MineType.PNG); was typo as I was trying all different things. Made correction in mail post as var decodedBytes = Utilities.base64Decode(strBase64Image);

Comment: Also tried adding base64 string directly but got same error. Had to truncate due to char limits. Code : var decodedBytes = Utilities.base64Decode("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABC4AAAHvCAYAAACbo54QAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3dUcxu2VkX8D9aE4P.................xIVUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");

Comment: Can you confirm my 3rd question in my 1st comment again?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for being patient. After following 3rd comment decode is successful, i.e. decode error is gone.  However now code is not allowing me to insert image in cell on sheet. Last two code lines `
var blobImg = Utilities.newBlob(decodedBytes, MimeType.PNG);

ss.insertImage(blobImg, 6, 3);` 
getting error **Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property insertImage on object SpreadsheetApp.Sheet. (line 5**.

Comment: @Tanaike  When tried following code where blob is extracted from file, image is rendered. `  

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/images/reports.png');

var binaryData = response.getContent();

var blob = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');

ss.insertImage(blob, 6, 3);`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your current situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Two things:

1. You need to strip off `data:image/png;base64,` from your Base64 string - the presence of this header is what gives you the error

   `Exception: Could not decode string.`
2. When you [create the blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata,-contenttype,-name), you need to give it a name: `var blobImg = Utilities.newBlob(decodedBytes, MimeType.PNG, 'MyImageName');` - as featured in the sample code [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row). 
   Otherwise you will get the error

   `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property insertImage on object SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.`.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestions to provide name to image has helped to solved error faced while creating blob.